# Pinvoke struct marshalling help needed - System.AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

Hey!
I've just begun fiddling with pinvoke and have encountered a problem. I'm getting the AccessViolationException. First of all, is there some way to debug or trace out which field is causing this error? The only thing being written to is the result struct.

The c++ call looks like:

```
MyFunc(int var1, _tuchar *var2, _tuchar *var3, _tuchar *var4, MyStruct *Result,
       _tuchar *var5, _tuchar *var6);
```

The c++ struct:

```
typedef struct MyStruct 
{
   _tuchar *id;
   _tuchar *ErrorMessages;
   int int1; 
   _tuchar language[3]; 
   _tuchar *result;
   int type;
   int number;
   int *type2; 
   _tuchar **blocks;
}
```

The C# struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string Id;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=500)]
    public char[] ErrorMessages;

    public int int1;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string language;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 15)]
    public char[] result;

    public int type;

    public int number;

    public int type2;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
    public string[] blocks;
```

The C# method declaration:

```
[DllImport(MyPath, EntryPoint = "MyEntryPoint", SetLastError = true,
           CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern int MyFunc(int var1, string var2, string var3,
      string var4, ref MyStruct Result, string var5, string var6);
```

The C# Call:

```
var result = new MyStruct();
MyFunc(0, "var2", "var3", "var4", ref result, "var5", "var6");
```

Hope I haven't left anything out.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does the `MyFunc` declaration look like in C#?

Comment: ah ofc i forgot something, thanks mate ^^

Comment: Is the size of `int` in C++ guaranteed to be 32-bits/convertible with System.Int32? System.Int32 has a very precise guarantee -- even across bit-ness.

Comment: Does `var*` parameters for input or for output?

Comment: @Anton Semenov var* are inputs

Comment: Debug this by cutting it down to something simple and then gradually build it up. That is the most basic technique that you should learn. Debug it by adding one field at a time to your struct. At the moment you appear to have no idea where to look and it's because you haven't simplified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ooooh, man! You've picked quite a complex case for your first fiddling experience. I recommend doing something simpler first, and then moving on to the real stuff.

**Firstly**, `CharSet=CharSet.Ansi` looks suspicious. All your strings and chars are `_tuchar`, and I gather the `u` in there means "Unicode", doesn't it? If that's the case, you need `CharSet=CharSet.Unicode`.

**Secondly**, (and this is the most likely culprit) why is the `ErrorMessages` field marshaled as `ByValArray`? You know that `ByVal` here means "by value", don't you? As in, **not** by reference. And you know that little asterisk thing in C++ means "reference", don't you? So why does your reference field `ErrorMessages` marshaled as a by-value array? In case you don't know, an array is generally said to be passed "by value" when all of it's content is being passed, instead of just passing a reference (pointer) to a memory location where all that content is stored. In C++ struct definition, you specify `_tuchar*`, which means "a reference (pointer) to some memory containing one or more of _tuchars", whereas in C# you specify `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=500)]`, which means "500 _tuchars are supposed to be here, no more and no less". Seeing how a reference (pointer) usually takes 4 bytes (or 8 bytes on 64bit machines), and 500 unicode characters take 1000 bytes, you have an obvious mismatch right here.

**Thirdly** and **fourthly**, same point goes for `result` and `blocks` fields.

**Fifthly**, the `language` field is exactly reverse situation: the C++ code says "there are 3 _tuchars here", while C# code says "there is a reference (pointer) to a string here" (in case you don't know, `LPStr` means "Long Pointer to STRing")

**And finally**, after you have fixed all those problems, I recommend you execute your program and print out the result of call to `Marshal.SizeOf( typeof( MyStruct ) )`. That will give you exactly how big your struct is, in .NET's opinion. The go on the C++ side and print out `sizeof( MyStruct )`. That will give you what C++ thinks about the size.

If they turn out different, see what's wrong. Try to remove fields one by one, until they become same. This will give you the culprit field(s). Work with them.

Overall, I suggest you need a better understanding of how things work first. This case is waaaay too complex for a beginner.

Good luck!

Comment: Well sir, you are the man : ) I thank you very much for your input. will see if i can solve this mess. One thing I can't really get my mind around are these strings that the c++ will write to... I thought well if i send a string with 500 chars then the c++ dll won't write outside of boundary. Is there a limit as to how big the result can be?

Comment: Could it be that having writable string fields in a struct is impossible? Or do you know how they should be defined (errormessages and result)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but have you tried decorating the string parameters with `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)`:

```
[DllImport(MyPath, EntryPoint = "MyEntryPoint", SetLastError = true,
    CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
internal static extern int MyFunc(
    int var1,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string var2, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string var3,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string var4,
    ref MyStruct Result,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string var5,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    string var6);
```

I believe that the default marshaling chosen for strings is `BStr` and `_tuchar` should expand to `wchar_t` so I'd guess that `LPWStr` is the correct marshalling method (pointer to a wide character string).

---

**Update:** Various things on `MyStruct` don't look quite right:

`ErrorMessages` is marked as `ByValArray`, and so the .Net interop is probably expecting `MyStruct` to look a bit like this:

```
typedef struct MyStruct 
{
   _tuchar *id;
   _tuchar ErrorMessages[500];
   // Rest of MyStruct
```

Which is probably going to cause problems - same thing for `result`.

Also I think that `language` *should* be using `ByValArray` with a size of 3.

Finally `blocks` should probably be passed using `LPArray` - `ByValArray` doesn't seem right.

(This is all mostly guesswork btw - I hope this is pointing you in the right direction but I don't have *that* much experience with P/Invoke interop)

---

**Another update:** On `MyStruct` you declare the charset to be Ansi, but on `MyFunc` its `Unicode`... is the unmanaged dll compiled with Unicode or Ansi?  If it uses Unicode then I believe that you should use `LPWStr` when marshalling strings, and with Ansi it should be `LPStr`.

Comment: hmm i will try decorating the strings, but these strings are only read, not written. i believe the problem is inside the result, i've read that string being written to should use stringbuilder, but you can't use stringbuilder in a struct without getting a marshalling exception. Don't know about uni or ansi, is there some way to figure it out?

Comment: @Dashu A few of the attributes on `MyStruct` don't seem quite right either - I've updated my question but be warned that I probably don't know what I'm talking about! :-p

Comment: @Dashu Just spotted that `MyStruct` is passed as a `ref` parameter and so I think that `ErrorMessages` is probably the source of your problem - as I understand it the .Net marshalling layer is expecting the size of `MyStruct` to be at least 500, when in fact it is a lot smaller than that.

Comment: Cannot marshal field 'language' of type 'MyStruct': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (String fields must be paired with LPStr, LPWStr, LPTStr, BStr, or ByValTStr). The runtime seems to say ^^

Comment: Yeah i can't quite figure out how to allocate memory for a string without using stringbuilder...

Comment: @Dashu Sorry, should have been more specific - you should either marshal `langauage` as a char array using `ByValArray`, or I believe that you can instead marshal it as a string using `ByValTStr`.